# Display Air Pollution Map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, web-service

King‘s College supports a real-time air pollution map, here is the link: https://www.londonair.org.uk/LondonAir/nowcast.aspx
I would like to display the map in QGIS , I.e. somewhat get the link to the map and add it as a layer.

Would that be possible?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Actually nothing and I am clueless of how it can be done.  I am  a bit familiar with WFS, but I am unable to connect the dots. I don’t even know where to start looking…

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. As a *problem-solving* site, we expect a certain level of due dilligence be performed before posting. The most frequently commented questions are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" Ideally, there exists a tutorial somewhere to get you started, and if that doesn't work, then you'll have a sufficiently focused problem to describe here.

Comment: I used my browser inspection tools to see where the network traffic was coming from, and deduced that it was an ArcGIS Server of some kind, tried the endpoint in QGIS and success. Note you should also please check with the data provider's terms and conditions before re-using their data in anything public or of high-usage. They have other tools for accessing data via their API links that you might want to use too.

Answer (score 2):

Create a New ArcGIS Rest service looking like this:

[image]

Then click it in the browser section to open the layers on the service, choose the layer, double-click to add to your map layers, producing the map:

[image]

Note that only the raster layers seem to work, the ones with polygon icons don't. No idea.

You can layer it over a background layer with "Multiply" blend mode and see the pollution levels overlaid on the streets.

[image]

Comment: Oh! Wow! Thank you so much, that was exactly what I wanted to know! Perfect!